# Show $a^2=6k+3 \Rightarrow a = 6n + 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $a^2=6k+3$, for some integer $k$, then also $a = 6n + 3$ for an integer n.

Or in in other words: $a^2=6k+3 \Rightarrow a = 6n + 3$.

Taking the square root, $a=\sqrt{6k+3}$, does not help. I've also looked after factorizations, but I haven't find anything useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more pedestrian approach is to note that *a* must have a factor of 3 in it (since the square of a is divisible by 3) and *a* must also be odd. If you use these two observations, you can also deduce that *a* must have the form 6n+3 for some natural number n.

Comment: I was about to post the following, which is entirely equivalent - Here is a descriptive solution to highlight what is going on.

$a^2$ is odd and divisible by $3$.

Since the square of an even number is even, $a$ must be odd. Since only the square of a number divisible by $3$ is divisible by $3$, $a$ must be divisible by $3$.

So $a$ must be an odd number divisible by $3$, hence of the form $3(2n+1)=6n+3$

Comment: @MarkBennet That's nice. My argument was basically a hybrid of yours and the other poster, since a being divisible by 3 and also having to be odd implies a = 3(2k+1), which when you square it basically has the form 6(6k$^2$+6k) + 9, and then you use the fact that 9 is equivalent to 3 (mod 6), to get 6(6k$^2$+6k+1) + 3.

Answer (score 5):

Any integer $a$ is  $\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2,3\pmod6$

$$a\equiv0\pmod6\implies a^2\equiv0\pmod 6$$

$$a\equiv\pm1\pmod6\implies a^2\equiv1\pmod 6$$

$$a\equiv\pm2\pmod6\implies a^2\equiv4\pmod 6$$

$$a\equiv3\pmod6\implies a^2\equiv9\equiv3\pmod 6$$